# can we remove saturday and sunday from Gantt chart view in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, office-365

Gantt chart is including the weekends. Is there an option to remove the weekends in out of the box sharepoint gantt chart?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option to achieve that as OOTB. The Gantt view does not depend on the regional setting of the site.